# My VPS does not accept HTTPS requests on a port other than 443

Tags: nginx, https, vps

I have a Contabo VPS (Ubuntu) where I want to run Nginx and Typebot.io, but I realized that only HTTPS requests are accepted via port 443. Remembering that UFW is disabled.
I've tried everything, please let someone help me!
I've already tried putting both typebot.io and Nginx to listen on another port.
I have already enabled UFW and released the desired ports. I've already consulted the documentation on Cloudflare's https (my website's DNS server), and YES, everything is correct, I'm using the recommended ports.
I think the problem is with the VPS or the problem is between the computer and the chair.